# WSO2 Data services server Optional input parameters for sql update

Tags: parameters, wso2, option-type

I have a sql that performs an "edit" operation.  The functionality of the edit should update if values are present and disregard if they are not, thus the need for optional input parameters.  For this functionality to work I need to get the Data Services Server to generate a wsdl/xsd with parameters that take 0 or more occurrences, but it seems like I can only get it to generate a request that requires 1 or more occurrences on all input parameters.  This means the edit operation would require every field as opposed to sending along only those fields that would be updated.

This previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326683/using-input-parameter-as-an-optional-input)! suggests the use of defaultValue on the param element as a way to generate the optional input parameters.

The snippet below shows some code from the rdbms_sample which ships with wso2 data services server. This code snippet contains the defaultValue=1500 for the salary input.  Which based on the post above and on the wso2 documentation for [defaultValues](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Default+Values+Sample)!  it should lead to the generation of an optional input parameter for the salary field.

```html
   <query id="addEmployeeQuery" useConfig="default">
      <sql>insert into Employees (employeeNumber, lastName, firstName, email, salary) values(:employeeNumber,:lastName,:firstName,:email,:salary)</sql>
      <param name="employeeNumber" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN"/>
      <param name="lastName" ordinal="2" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN">
         <validateLength maximum="20" minimum="3"/>
      </param>
      <param name="firstName" ordinal="3" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN"/>
      <param name="email" ordinal="4" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="STRING" type="IN">
         <validatePattern pattern="(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|&quot;(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*&quot;)@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])"/>
      </param>
      <param defaultValue="1500" name="salary" ordinal="5" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="DOUBLE" type="IN"/>
   </query>
```

When observing the snippet below please notice that the salary is expecting exactly one occurrence not 0 or 1 occurrences as the documentation seems to indicate when a default value is present.

```html
<body>
   <p:addEmployee xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:employeeNumber xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">?</xs:employeeNumber>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:lastName xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">?</xs:lastName>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:firstName xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">?</xs:firstName>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:email xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">?</xs:email>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:salary xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">?</xs:salary>
   </p:addEmployee>
</body>
```

What do I need to do to make all of the above parameters optional on an add/update case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very complex issue with many variables which require much focus. It should first be understood that by default, a database schema should:

1. prescribe whether a column is allowed to contain a NULL value or not, and
2. if an initial value is not specified, what default value should be assigned to a column.

I will refer to these two as the "Nullable" characteristic and the other as the "Default value" characteristic of a column, per the database schema. Most modern database engines provide for definition of these characteristics and will allow any combination of the two to exist. (Further discussion of the resultant combination of these two characteristics is outside the realm of our question at hand.)

Next, the Data Service Resource Language (DSRL) used in the WSO2 DSS is a derivative of XML. The DSRL is used to define queries and operations of the services. When defining the query part of a service definition, one can assign a literal default value or an Internal Property Value for the parameter elements. An example of a literal default would be defaultValue="1500". The Internal Property Values defined are: #{USERNAME}, #{NULL}, #{TENANT_ID}, and #{USER_ROLES}. See this URL for more details:
     https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS311/Adding+Input+Mappings

For both your add and update queries, you will need to assign a defaultValue=#{NULL} to any parameters that you want to be optional for the operation call. Note that for the add, you will need to either

1. provide a value for those elements not assigned a defaultValue in the query definition or
2. ensure a default value is specified in the database schema, or finally
3. that per the database schema the column is Nullable

As you noted, it seems the parameter elements must all be present in the request, however this is not necessarily true. The post you referred to previously noted at the end that "you can call 'getEmployees' without 'employeeNumber' and get all employees". Meaning: you do NOT have to include the element in the operation request at all, even though the documentation inserted during creation of the data service which says "exactly 1 occurrence" leads you to believe so.

For both the INSERT (add operation) and UPDATE (edit operation), if you add a defaultValue of #{NULL} in the query definition, it does in fact make the parameter element optional to an extent. Optional, in the context of NOT HAVING to provide the element at all in the operation call. However, this will still throw a SQL error on your database if you don't do something in the SQL UPDATE statement to handle a NULL value contained in one of these optional parameters.

In an edit operation, the most desirable solution would be one that would allow you to provide any of the optional elements with a new value you want to update, while leaving those columns that are not included in your update request unchanged.

To make the data service work like this, here is what we did:

1. Assign a default value in query definition for the parameters that are optional, using #{NULL} as the value:

> ```
>  <param defaultValue="#{NULL}" name="employeeNumber" ordinal="1" paramType="SCALAR" sqlType="INTEGER" type="IN"/>
> ```

2. Use the ANSI SQL ISNULL() function in your update statement to assign the value to each column that you want potentially to be optional (that you want to leave unchanged) when you invoke your update operation:

   update Employees SET employeeNumber=ISNULL(?, employeeNumber), lastName=ISNULL(?, lastName),  ... where employeeID = ?;

   NOTE: You will not change the insert statement for your add operation
3. Completely remove the parameter element(s) for columns you wish to leave unchanged during your update operation. The insertion of the ISNULL() function in the  definition above will compare the first argument provided with NULL and return that parameter's value if the parameter is not null. Otherwise the function will return the value of the second parameter, in this case, the existing value in the table row you are updating (leaving that column's value unchanged).

e.g. To perform an add operation that only populates a provided employee number, but leaves the other columns to their database schema defaults, you invoke the operation like this:

```
 </body>
      <p:addEmployee xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">
           <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
           <xs:employeeNumber xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">15432</xs:employeeNumber>
      </p:addEmployee>
 </body>
```

e.g. To perform an edit operation that only updates the employee last name, but leaves the other columns to their existing values, you invoke the operation like this:

```
 </body>
      <p:editEmployee xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">
           <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
           <xs:employeeLastName xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/samples/rdbms_sample">Jones</xs:employeeLastName>
      </p:editEmployee>
 </body>
```

Note that none of the other parameter elements were included in the operation call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326683/using-input-parameter-as-an-optional-input

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you can create a proxy service in WSO2 ESB, with a WSDL that have input parameters optional, and validate if they are present or not, and take action them. If the parameters are present in the request message then call the dataservice. I also I´m searching the same as you but without results.

Answer (score 0):

**defaultValue="#{NULL}" optional="true"** helps to do parameters optional.

```
<query id="GET_ADDRESS_BY_NAME" useConfig="TEST">
<sql>SELECT country, street, housenumber 
    FROM TABLE (PKG_SEARCH_DATA.FN_GET_ADDRESS_BY_NAME (:FIRSTNAME,:LASTNAME))</sql>
     <result outputType="json">{"Start":{"data":[{"country":"$country", "street":"$street", "housenumber":"$housenumber"}]}}</result>
     <param name="FIRSTNAME" defaultValue="#{NULL}" optional="true" sqlType="STRING"/>
     <param name="LASTNAME" defaultValue="#{NULL}" optional="true" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
```